# Python - Easiest way to scrape text from list of URLs using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, screen-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-scraping

What's the easiest way to scrape just the text from a handful of webpages (using a list of URLs) using BeautifulSoup? Is it even possible?

Best,
Georgina

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import urllib2
import BeautifulSoup
import re

Newlines = re.compile(r'[\r\n]\s+')

def getPageText(url):
    # given a url, get page content
    data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    # parse as html structured document
    bs = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(data, convertEntities=BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup.HTML_ENTITIES)
    # kill javascript content
    for s in bs.findAll('script'):
        s.replaceWith('')
    # find body and extract text
    txt = bs.find('body').getText('\n')
    # remove multiple linebreaks and whitespace
    return Newlines.sub('\n', txt)

def main():
    urls = [
        'http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/5331266/python-easiest-way-to-scrape-text-from-list-of-urls-using-beautifulsoup',
        'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330248/how-to-rewrite-a-recursive-function-to-use-a-loop-instead'
    ]
    txt = [getPageText(url) for url in urls]

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

It now removes javascript and decodes html entities.

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly possible. Easiest way is to iterate through list of URLs, load the content, find the URLs, add them to main list. Stop iteration when enough pages are found.

Just some tips:

- `urllib2.urlopen` for fetching content
- `BeautifulSoup`:  findAll('a') for finding URLs

Comment: Hi @Jiri -- do you mean "find the HTML" ?

Comment: Ok, you dont need to traverse site by URLs in pages. Just to strip text. You can try ''.join(soup.findAll(text=True))

Answer (score 1):

I know that it is not an answer to your exact question (about BeautifulSoup) but a good idea is to have a look at [Scrapy](http://doc.scrapy.org/intro/overview.html) which seems to fit yous needs.