# Scrape html files stored in remote directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I have thousands of html files stored in a remote directory. All these files have same HTML structure. Right now I am scraping every file manually with the following script

```
from string import punctuation, whitespace
import urllib2
import datetime
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
import csv
today = datetime.date.today()
html = urllib2.urlopen("http://hostname/coimbatore/3BHK_flats_inCoimbatore.html_%94201308110608%94.html").read()

soup = Soup(html)
for li in soup.findAll('li', attrs={'class':'g'}):
    sLink = li.find('a')
    print sLink['href']
    sSpan = li.find('span', attrs={'class':'st'})
    print sSpan
```

So the above script is for one URL. Like wise I wanna scrape through all the html files which are under that directory irrespective of the file names. I do not find that this question has been asked.

**Update** : Code

```
import urllib2
import BeautifulSoup
import re

Newlines = re.compile(r'[\r\n]\s+')

def getPageText(url):
    # given a url, get page content
 data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    # parse as html structured document
 bs = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(data, convertEntities=BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup.HTML_ENTITIES)
    # kill javascript content
 for li in bs.findAll('li', attrs={'class':'g'}):
  sLink = li.find('a')
  print sLink['href']
  sSpan = li.find('span', attrs={'class':'st'})
  print sSpan
def main():
    urls = [
        'http://192.168.1.200/coimbatore/3BHK_flats_inCoimbatore.html_%94201308110608%94.html',
        'http://192.168.1.200/coimbatore/3BHK_flats_inCoimbatore.html_%94201308110608%94.html.html'
    ]
    txt = [getPageText(url) for url in urls]

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Get list of files in the directory, do the process for each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use loop:

```
...

for url in url_list:
    html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()

    soup = Soup(html)
    for li in soup.findAll('li', attrs={'class':'g'}):
        sLink = li.find('a')
        print sLink['href']
        sSpan = li.find('span', attrs={'class':'st'})
        print sSpan
```

If you don't know url list in advance, you have to parse listing page.

---

```
import csv
import urllib2

import BeautifulSoup


def getPageText(url, filename):
    data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    bs = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(data, convertEntities=BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup.HTML_ENTITIES)
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        for li in bs.findAll('li', attrs={'class':'g'}):
            sLink = li.find('a')
            sSpan = li.find('span', attrs={'class':'st'})
            writer.writerow([sLink['href'], sSpan])

def main():
    urls = [
        'http://192.168.1.200/coimbatore/3BHK_flats_inCoimbatore.html_%94201308110608%94.html',
        'http://192.168.1.200/coimbatore/3BHK_flats_inCoimbatore.html_%94201308110608%94.html.html',
    ]
    for i, url in enumerate(urls, 1):
        getPageText(url, '{}.csv'.format(i))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Dammit, you're fast. Great answer bro :)

Comment: @falsetru . Now how do it do that URL list? Should I have to store all the URL in a file? on pass it like the following  `urls = [
        'http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/5331266/python-easiest-way-to-scrape-text-from-list-of-urls-using-beautifulsoup',
        'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330248/how-to-rewrite-a-recursive-function-to-use-a-loop-instead'
    ]`?

Comment: @Venky, Without knowing the url pattern or the listing page structure, I can't answer.

Comment: @Venky, Where do you get the url list?

Comment: @falsetru . I have update the code which used two URLs. Can I manipulate it so that output of each file get stored in diff .csv file? and let me know if there is any efficient way of doing what I have done already.

Comment: @Venky, See updated answer. I coulnd't test the code because I can't acess the weg page.