# python doesn't get page content

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I've got the Python Beautifulsoup script below (adapted to python 3 from that [script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5331504/10789707) ).
It executes fine but nothing is returned in cmd.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

Newlines = re.compile(r'[\r\n]\s+')

def getPageText(url):
    # given a url, get page content
    data = urlopen(url).read()
    # parse as html structured document
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
    # kill javascript content
    for s in soup.findAll('script'):
        s.replaceWith('')
    # find body and extract text
    txt = soup.find('body').getText('\n')
    # remove multiple linebreaks and whitespace
    return Newlines.sub('\n', txt)

def main():
    urls = [
        'http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/5331266/python-easiest-way-to-scrape-text-from-list-of-urls-using-beautifulsoup',
        'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330248/how-to-rewrite-a-recursive-function-to-use-a-loop-instead'
    ]
    txt = [getPageText(url) for url in urls]

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Here's my cmd output

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0..]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\user\Desktop\urls>python urls.py

C:\Users\user\Desktop\urls>
```

Why doesn't it return the pages contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is returned in cmd because there is no `print` statement in the code.
if you want to print out all the texts parsed from the given URL just use `print` function in `main()` function

```py
def main():
    urls = [
        'http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/5331266/python-easiest-way-to-scrape-text-from-list-of-urls-using-beautifulsoup',
        'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330248/how-to-rewrite-a-recursive-function-to-use-a-loop-instead'
    ]
    txt = [getPageText(url) for url in URLs]
    for t in txt:
        print(t)
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot Giorgi! worked well. I'll test it large scale and be back. Be well!