# Simple loop Ackermann function

Tags: algorithm, loops

How to write the [Ackermann function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function) with a simple non-recursive loop?

Comment: And what kind of homework is this?

Comment: @Henk: not a homework, just curious about the expressive power of simple loops.

Comment: Apparently, the Ackermann function is not **primitively recursive** — it’s impossible to refactor it into a loop. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i7sm9dzFtEI

Comment: Also, questions that are theoretical/architectural in nature are better suited on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: To be clear, it cannot be implemented with only _for loops_ (i.e. it isn't primitive recursive), it can be with only _while loops_ (which every computable function can, by definition).

Answer (score 5):

Here's a possible implementation:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class LinearAckermann {

    static ArrayList<Long> mList = new ArrayList<Long>();

    public static long ackermann(long m, long n) {
        while (true) {
            if (m == 0) {
                n += 1;
                if (mList.isEmpty()) {
                    return n;
                } else {
                    int index = mList.size() - 1;
                    m = mList.get(index);
                    mList.remove(index);
                }
            } else if (n == 0) {
                m -= 1;
                n = 1;
            } else {
                mList.add(m - 1);
                n -= 1;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(ackermann(4, 1));
    }
}
```

It uses `mList` instead of a stack to hold pending work; when the stack becomes empty, it can return the accumulated value.

Comment: What is _this_ supposed to do, and how does it augment the accepted answer?

Comment: this is a non-recursive implementation of Ackermann's function, check the results and see that it really gives the same results. besides this answer I don't understand what you would expect exactly.

Comment: It is surprising that we came up with almost the exact same code -- just in two different languages.

Comment: Did you copy this from somewhere, or did you come up with the code yourself?

Comment: I remember I saw a video on youtube saying it was not possible to have a non recursive implementation, and I asked to myself why wouldn't it be and I saw no reason, tried and this is what I've got. The code is all composed by me.

Answer (score 0):

The following "iterative" version of Ackermann’s function
(using lists of natural numbers) is a simple loop, expressed using tail recursion.

```
ackloop (n::0::list) = ackloop (n+1::list)
ackloop (0::m::list) = ackloop (1::m-1::list)
ackloop (n::m::list) = ackloop (n-1::m::m-1::list)
ackloop [m] = m
```

Now ack(m,n) = ackloop [n,m].