# Define stack size in a parallel for loop C#

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, stack-overflow

I am implementing a random forest algorithm. Each tree is trained in a recursive fashion (increasing the size of the call stack as the tree gets deeper) and I can train one tree without any problem (or several trees in a sequential loop).

Training all the trees in a Parallel.For loop, however, leads to a stack overflow. I am aware that the stack size can be configured when using new Thread(), as stated in : [How to change stack size for a .NET program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556938/how-to-change-stack-size-for-a-net-program)

However, is it possible to do it with Parallel.For ? Or do I have to write all my threads, specifying the size of their stack ?

Comment: Consider using a `Stack<T>` and rewriting the method as iterative.

Comment: @Bas, could you be a little bit more specific (or send a link) please ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/531668/which-recursive-functions-cannot-be-rewritten-using-loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [social.msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/119571d3-d155-4416-a71d-6bbd5f13bbc1/parallel-stack-size?forum=parallelextensions):

> By default, TPL uses threads from the CLR ThreadPool.  The stack size
>   for a ThreadPool thread is the process' default stack size, which is
>   determined by the executable file containing the process entry point.
>
> You can change the default stack size for the process by editing this
>   setting in the executable.  One way to do this is with "editbin.exe,"
>   which comes with Vistual Studio.  If your executable is
>   "myprogram.exe" and you want a 2MB stack, you might run:
>
> editbin /stack:2097152 myprogram.exe
>
> Hope that helps!