# Start new line with spaces

Tags: c#

I'm stuck at this problem I would really appreciate if someone can help me solve this problem.

1. I want to add spaces for sub-folder like this format down below.(it must be done with recursion)
2. I want to add spaces for sub-folder like this format down below.(it
   must be done with recursion)

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;
   using System.IO;

   namespace G14_211115
   {
        class Program
        {
              static void Main(string[] args)
              {
                   string path = @"C:\Program Files\FinchVPN";

                   WriteDirectories(path);
                   Console.ReadKey();
              }

              /* Tasks.
              * 1. I want to add spaces for subfolder like this format down below. ( it must be done with recursion) 
              *    Like this
              *    --------------------------------------------------------------
              *    Folder 1
              *      Folder 1.1
              *      Folder 1.2
              *    Folder 2
              *      Folder 2.1
              *        Folder 2.1.1
              *      Folder 2.2
              *    Folder 3
              *    Folder 4
              *   
               * 2. Task 2 I want to retype this code without using recurrence and C# inbuilt functions.
              */

              static void WriteDirectories(string path)
              {
                   string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(path);

                   for(int i = 0; i < dirs.Length; i++)
                   {
                        Console.WriteLine(dirs[i]); 
                        WriteDirectories(dirs[i]);
                   }
             }
        }
   }
   ```

Comment: Is there any differenve between 1) and 2) ?

Comment: When you say "recurrence" do you mean "recursion"?

Comment: I've written a similar code that also draws lines to children, like in those really cool DOS programs. This is quite a fun challenge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you are calling `WriteDirectories` recursivly, you can pass a variable to each call indicating the `(recursion)level`. Using this you can just put some spaces before the output.

Therefore you would need to modify your code like this:

```
static void WriteDirectories(string path, int level = 0)
{
    string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(path);

    for (int i = 0; i < dirs.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < level; j++)
        {
            Console.Write(" ");
        }

        Console.WriteLine(dirs[i]);
        WriteDirectories(dirs[i], (level + 1));
    }
}
```

If you want more than just one space per level you can simply modify the inner loop, `j < 2 * level` would give you 2 space characters per level, and so on.

**Update (Thanks to David)**

Instead of the inner loop you can use `new string(' ', level)` for creating a new string containing the specified character `level`-times.

So the inner `for`-loop would be replaced by `Console.Write(new string(' ', level));`.

Comment: Instead of the inner `for` loop, just do `Console.Write(new string(' ', level));`

Comment: @DavidG I know that of course but I am pretty sure this is a homework and he is not on that level right now ;-)

Comment: If it's homework then don't answer it, don't use it as an excuse to show "lower" quality code.

Comment: Markus this is not homework this was homework once upon a time. I was studying C# 2 year ago and than I had a pause. I forgot everything right now.
I was saving all homeworks and not I want to begin it from the start. thanks for answering btw.
what about doing this without recurrence and inbuilt functions?

Comment: @NikushaKalatozi Solving this issue without recursion can be done by using a loop and a data structure like a stack. You can look at [http://stackoverflow.com/a/531704/2921691](this) answer for example.

Comment: What about this code? the allign is wrong for it... 
it's not like
Folder 1
           *      Folder 1.1
           *      Folder 1.2
it's like 
Folder 1
           *      Folder 1.1
           *        Folder 1.2
http://postimg.org/image/zdodzz7q3/

Comment: @NikushaKalatozi Yeah, that's a little bug... replace `WriteDirectories(dirs[i], (++level));` with `WriteDirectories(dirs[i], (level + 1));` and it will work. I' ve updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

just provide a depth-parameter to your recursive call and add spaces according to the depth.

```
       static void WriteDirectories(string path, int depth) {
            string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
            for(int i = 0; i < dirs.Length; i++) {
                 string preSpaces = new String(' ',depth);
                 Console.WriteLine(preSpaces + dirs[i]); 
                 WriteDirectories(dirs[i], depth+1);
            }
       }
```

Your first call should provide 0 or 1 as depth.

Comment: getting a downvote for what? My answer resembles Markus', which has been upvoted...don't get it.